# Wire transfer from America

Tags: usa, money

Does anyone know of any bank in America that will execute a wire transfer to another country for a customer who does not hold an account with them? Or do most banks require you to hold an account with them?

Comment: I think you are looking for Western Union...

Comment: And if the OP is looking for Western Union (or Moneygram, which had lower fees at my last check), *remember that the money you send can not be recovered; if it is a scam you are screwed*.

Comment: You don't need an account with any bank to do a transfer. You can walk upto the teller, show your id, give the teller the amount, fill in the transfer form, pay the fee and take a receipt. If the amount is above a certain limit (usually, $10,000 or the equivalent in local currency) you have to provide a source of funds.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid That sounds like an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus No different from a wire transfer, cashier's check or money order...

Comment: @user71659 With a wire transfer, there's an account at the other end. There's whatever documentation that country requires for setting up a bank account—at least a verified name. With Western Union, all you need is the correct password.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus Not true. You need the same documentation to pickup WU in the US as you do to open a bank account: [photo id](https://www.westernunion.com/us/en/why-do-i-need-to-bring-picture-id-to-pick-up-money.html), and if transactions exceed a certain amount, SSN. This is due to anti-money laundering regulations.

Comment: The money isn't going to the USA; it's headed for some third country.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus The whole point is that the statement "With Western Union, all you need is the correct password." is demonstrably false in the US and worldwide.

Comment: @user71659 OK, you win: In some countries where fraud flourishes, all you need for Western Union is a password. In the USA you will need ID. However, you have, as far as I know, no control over which WU office is used for pickup, so the person who says he is renting his apartment in New York City will pick up your 50% deposit in [Romania](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2840697/The-scourge-Scamville-Romanian-town-cyber-crime-capital-world-hundreds-fraudsters-rake-millions-gullible-online-shoppers.html). Link: "Western Union and Money Gram offices sprouted like the weeds…"

Answer (score 3):

Where would the money come from, if you do not have an account with that bank? Are you trying to bring cash to a bank to turn in to a wire?

In any case, the answer is probably *no*. Banks are required to verify identity for international transfers as an anti-terrorism and anti-laundering practice. Nothing, as far as I know, stops you from opening an account in a bank, depositing the money, and sending a wire with it, provided you have suitable identification.

We might be of more help if we knew why you needed to do this, in case alternative methods of transfer are available. For small amounts, for example, you could use an International Postal Money Order.

Comment: "In any case, the answer is probably no. Banks are required to verify identity for international transfers as an anti-terrorism and anti-laundering practice" can't the bank verify the ID without the opening a new account?

Answer (score 2):

I've personally used [TransferWise](https://transferwise.com/). To send to and from the USA, seem to be pretty low rates and easy to use. You do not need to have the same bank as the sender or receiver. Was using PayPal at first but that's very expensive especially when sending a big amount.

Answer (score 1):

I've used http://xe.com/ and https://www.moneycorp.com/uk/ to move money from the the US to Europe (family). My bank would do it as well, but these services are a lot cheaper.

Of course you need an account with them, but it's not a big deal: open the account, deposit the money, transfer the money, close the account or let it sit empty. It's similar to opening an account with an online retailer like amazon.com.